# Eclipse - minimum workspace directories to be put in version management system

Tags: eclipse

I want all workspace settings to be stored in clearcase and to be able to create a new workspace using cp command. i tried copying only .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings and .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects from a working workspace - but in new workspace project explorer does not shows any projects / working sets. 
i am using eclipse Juno (4.2) on Linux.

== Script to copy old workspace to new

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set old = old_workspace
set new = workspace2

rm -rf $new
mkdir -p $new
cd $new
mkdir -p .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime
cp -r $old/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/    .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/
cp -r $old/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/* .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/
chmod -R +w .
```

===
This is the full list of .metadata/.plugins/ of woking workspace :

com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh  org.eclipse.debug.core               org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover  org.eclipse.team.core
net.sourceforge.eclipseccase          org.eclipse.debug.ui                 org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring     org.eclipse.team.cvs.core
org.eclipse.birt.chart.engine         org.eclipse.dltk.core                org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring       org.eclipse.ui.editors
org.eclipse.cdt.core                  org.eclipse.e4.workbench             org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core      org.eclipse.ui.ide
org.eclipse.cdt.make.core             org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.recording  org.eclipse.mylyn.context.core       org.eclipse.ui.workbench
org.eclipse.cdt.make.ui               org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk        org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui           org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor
org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core   org.eclipse.jdt.core                 org.eclipse.pde.core                 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core
org.eclipse.cdt.ui                    org.eclipse.jdt.launching            org.eclipse.rse.core                 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui
org.eclipse.core.resources            org.eclipse.jdt.ui                   org.eclipse.rse.ui                   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core
org.eclipse.core.runtime              org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core             org.eclipse.search

Comment: What are you trying to put in your SCM ? you are trying to copy the projects of the workspace or only the settings of the workspace?

Comment: You might be interested in Workspace Mechanic. It might be an alternative solution to the problem you're trying to solve? https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/

Comment: i want to add workspace files to SCM. project setting .project/.cproject are already part of SCM.

Answer (score 0):

Your script copies the settings of the workspace ($old/.metadata/...), but you are missing the workspace contents itself ($old/filesAndDirectories).